# How do I "unhide" or "show" a hidden login item on Mountain Lion?

Tags: login

I accidentally hid a bunch of login items, some of which I meant to delete. How do I unhide these items once they're hidden?

Answer (score 1):

Press command and tab to see the apps that are "running" and select the apps one by one to reveal the windows that the system hid for you.

Alternately, you could deselect the hidden check in the log in items preference and restart (or log out and in again).

Comment: Thanks for that! Looks like I hid AND deleted them, so they're really not there! I thought I'd only hidden them and couldn't, for the life of me, figure out a way to get them to show in the list again! :D Thanks for the help, appreciate it!

Comment: As an aside, I've noticed that Sophos' Anti virus isn't showing in the login menu items list, but it is starting up at log-on. It doesn't show when I command tab either, but the icon is in the menu bar up top and the program is running. Any idea why it doesn't show in the list of login items?

Comment: Not all apps run as UI - which is how the system adds things. You will need to look in LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons everywhere launchd will look to be sure no other background processes are running. Search here for more launchd answers :-)